# How variables are created inside a class when the class is not real?

Tags: java, oop

I have read a class is a model for creating objects and **does not exist physically** whereas Objects are real. But we are creating variables inside a class and are even manipulating them.

1. How is that possible when class does not exist physically?
2. When is the memory created for these variables?
3. Where is the memory created for these variables?

Comment: In the case of static variables, see hyde's answer. In the case of instance variables, well... say hello to the `new` operator (keyword) which will trigger the actual allocation.

Comment: What you read is wrong.  There is indeed a Class object for each class that has been loaded in Java.  In other languages like C++ the "reality" of the class is in the bytes of the compiled code, where, in addition to instructions for creating objects there may be "static" storage locations which represent static variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean static class variables, they are quaranteed to be initualized and any static initialization code inside class is quaranteed to be run, before the class is used. Exactly when, that is not specified IIRC, and different JVMs may do it at different time. They are basically same thing as global variables in languages which have those.

So to reiterate: static stuff exists and is initialized before it is first used. JVM implementation takes care of that.

But there is an object: instance of the class object, which is subclass of [class Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

---

Addition: In fact, in Java classes exist so concretely, that they can be serialized, transferred over network to different JVM, deserialized there, objects of the class created there and code executed. Simple example of this are vanilla Java applets running in browser. Another example is slave nodes in Jenkins/Hudson CI system, where the slave program is very small and only contains code to receive, deserialize and instantiate both classes and objects of these classes, sent by the master server they're connected to.

Answer (score 3):

Try thinking of it this way.  This is NOT an accurate explanation of exactly how any Java runtime does this, but a way of thinking of the class/object duality that may help you.

When you write a class X, you describe both code and data.  The runtime will need only one copy of some things -- the code and static variables, for instance -- and one copy per object of other things, like the instance variables.  You describe both these things in the class file you write, even though they will be stored separately.

Think of the one-copy-per-class things as all being stored in a block of memory together -- it would be called a struct in C.  In Java, the first time the class X is referenced in your program, the runtime allocates this block of memory and associates it with the class X.

When the program executes a statement such as "X x1 = new X()", the runtime allocates another block of memory (or struct) containing all the instance variables, and keeps a separate pointer to that associated with the x1 variable.

Now, when the program executes something like "Arc arc = x1.getArc();", the runtime uses the first pointer to reference the code in the method getArc(), and the second pointer to reference the instance variables associated with x1, and executes the indicated code using those instance variables.

OO programming provides this way of associating data with code that manipulates it, allowing us to organize the program as 'objects' of combined code and data.  The runtime does the business of keeping track of the different copies of things for us.

And I think it's inaccurate to say the class will not exist, it just won't exist in the form in which you wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

Classes do exist Physically in the JVM at runtime. The explaination that you read was trying to labour point A while leaving the rest of the detail for later. School and books do this all of the time.

Within the Oracle JVM classes have physical representation from the moment that they are loaded. Infact every object has a pointer to that class and many objects can point at the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think of a class or objects as physical things, that seems confusing to me. A class is often described as a blueprint for an object. Objects must be instantiated (created) using the `new` keyword, when an object is instantiated the class of the object is used as a blueprint to create the basic default object. The object may then be manipulated, even at runtime,  by referencing the location in memory where it is stored and using methods inside the object's class to manipulate the fields inside the object's class, at least this is the way it usually should be done, its what's known as encapsulation and is incredibly important in OOP so if you're not familiar with encapsulation I would recommend looking into it.

I mentioned an object can be manipulated at runtime, that is a major difference between an object and a class. Classes can as well using something called reflection but that's another topic for another day. A variable or field is sometimes described as an address, it is a reference to the location in memory where the object is stored. Objects are not accessed directly, they are referenced through variables.

```
JLabel label;
```

The code above is setting aside a location in memory to store a `JLabel` object when it is instantiated with the `new` keyword. So far there has not been an object created, we have declared a variable which is a reference to the location in memory where our object WILL be stored when it is created. We are not going to access our JLabel object directly, we are going to use the 'label' variable we've created to reference the actual object in memory. So if we create two `JLabel` objects and instantiate them, like this...

```
JLabel label;
label = new JLabel();
JLabel anotherLabel = new JLabel("this is another label");
```

we now have two JLabel objects. The first object first declares a variable to reference the object then instantiates it on a separate line. The second object declares the reference to it and instantiates it all in one line. You can create objects either way and there are different reasons for using both of these methods. When an object is created at least one of its constructor is called the first object calls the constructor inside of the `JLabel` class that takes no parameters; The second object uses the constructor inside the `JLabel` class that takes a `String` and creates the object displaying the text passed in to the constructor.

Now imagine the program is running and we want to change the first object so it will display some text because it currently is blank since we used the constructor that doesn't take any parameters. We can manipulate the object using the `setText(String)` method like this.

```
label.setText("now the first label displays text");
```

We have not altered the `JLabel` class in any way by using that method, however we have changed the object so now it displays text. I'm probably going to lose a bunch of reputation points, or whatever they are, for this answer because I probably didn't explain every detail exactly correct but I answered this question because you're asking something that was pretty difficult for me to understand for a long time, probably more so than most because I've never taken a programming class. There's so much to this I cant possibly explain this entirely without writing a book so I didn't go into things like scope, access modifiers, static, etc., but I tried to cover what I think is important to understand what you're asking. Like I said, I have no formal education so take my answer for what its worth but hopefully I was able to make it a little easier to understand.

Oh I forgot about your other question. A location in memory to store an object is declared when a variable for the object is created. At that point there is a location but the size in memory is still 0 or null because there is no object. The memory necessary to actually store the object will be filled when the object is instantiated.